# How to set style to Content-ID image in a Javax.mail?

Tags: java, html, email, jakarta-mail

I use the Javax.mail package to create and send e-mails to customers. In this e-mail I put severals pictures, a one for the background and other which are in front of that background. During my test, in html, I make several img object and determine the in-line style, instead of CSS, to put the others img object in front of my background.

I use the following code for adding a picture in my mail, not in attachment but in the mail, like the receiver have not to download it to see it :

```
[...]
messageBodyPart.setContent(htmlBody, "text/html");

MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
DataSource fds = new FileDataSource("c:/avaries_porteur2.png");
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID","<image>");
// add it
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
[...]
```

In my htmlBody variable I have put the following code :

```
htmlBody.append("<img src=\"cid:image\" style=\"position:absolute; z-index:0;\" >");
```

But despite my effort the style doesn't appear in my mails. I would like how to add, if it possible, the effect of my style to my image.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the mail reader. See [this link](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) for more information.

Comment: I check my mail on a Gmail client. But when I inspect the DOm of my mail the style argument on the img object, always in the mail's DOM, is not present.

Comment: Perhaps Gmail is removing it?